# Share photo to Instagram with hashtag

Tags: android, ios, share, instagram, hashtag

We are developing an iOS & Android app for an event.

One of the features the client wants is for users to snap a photo in the app and share it on instagram with the specific hashtag for the event.

Is there a way to share a photo to instagram with the hashtag pre-populated (we want to avoid users having to enter the hashtag manually, which they may forget to do or may misspell etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We never found a solution, so instead we showed some brief instructions on the screen before the user shares the photo on Instagram. The instructions tell them the hashtag to use when sharing. This was the best we could do .

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with default share option of iOS, as if you will pass image with any text string in activity item, the "Instagram" option from share menu will be disappear.